# setting up sftp users only second instances of sshd

Tags: chroot, sftp, sshd

I created second instances of sshd called `sshd-sftponly` and using different port (e.g 2222 ) and made all necessary changes in

`/etc/rc.d/init.d/sshd-sftponly` and  `/etc/ssh/sshd_config-sftponly`

Configuration in my /etc/ssh/sshd_config-sftponly  file for SFTP is :

```
Match group sftponly
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no
    ChrootDirectory /srv/h%
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Created user and group :

```
#groupadd sftponly
#useradd –g sftponly –d /srv/sftpuser –s /sbin/nologin sftpuser  
#passwd sftp
```

sshd-sftponly  second instances service restarted :

```
#/etc/init.d/sshd-sftponly restart
```

Pemission and ownership :

```
755 root:root /srv
```

and

```
700 sftpuser:sftponly /srv/sftpuser
```

Now after connection established of  sftp on 2222 port using “ sftpuser” user credential . it’s view full “/” path

I want to access or view only  /srv/sftpuser (i.e user home directory )

Note : without disturbing any configuration running for first  sshd instances .

Any suggestions?

Comment: You have got a typo on line `ChrootDirectory /srv/h%`. It should be `ChrootDirectory /srv/%u`. Anyway, check for errors you see in log.